# Sentry mixing errors

Tags: sendgrid, sentry

I'm trying to loop through a response object and send individual errors to Sentry. I'm working with the Sendgrid API response array of errors.

I have tried the below code, but it doesn't seem to work with Sentry.

```
try {
    await SendgridCall()
} catch (errors) {
  errors.response.body.errors.forEach(error => {
     let err = new Error(error.message)
     err.name = 'SendgridError'
     Sentry.captureException(err);
  })
}
```

I expect Sentry to create different error events based on the error message, but that doesn't seem to be happening. Instead it is merging most of the errors, and creating error events with mixed message (top message is different from message inside the event in the console).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The events are getting grouped in a single issue.

Please note you can still see the individual events:

[image: Cycle through issues in sentry.io]

By default Sentry will show you the newest one.

If you'd like to change how they get grouped, [you could use `fingerprint`](https://docs.sentry.io/data-management/rollups/?platform=browser) for that.
Be aware that by default Sentry will notify you (i.e email) for each new issue.

Comment: That does make sense. I can see that Sentry picks a message for the error description, but if I browse errors back and forth the message is different. So you're right, they are grouped. I would have thought that Errors with different messages have fingerprints that are too different to be grouped though. I will try setting the fingerprint then :) Thanks!